# Find length of selected checkbox having same title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some check-box which are loading dynamically. They have same class name but they have different title attribute. I want to find number of check-box selected which are having same title attribute.

```
<input class="checkme" type="checkbox" title="dynamically generated" />
```

Comment: where is the html? what is the class name? How did you specify the title? Is that an attribute?

Comment: Explain your question by giving reference to your code.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi class name is randomly given "checkme" and YES the title is an attribute and the check box is defined as:
<input class="checkme"  type="checkbox" title="dynamically generated" />"

Comment: How about the below answers? Do those meet your requirement?

Comment: yea thanks guys 
var count = $(":checkbox[title='something']:checked").length;
this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the pseudo-selector `:checked` to filter only selected checkbox :

```
var count = $(":checkbox[title='something']:checked").length;
```

## [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/egz83qy7/)

- `:checkbox` : select all elements has attribute `type` equals to `checkbox`
- `[title='something']` : select all elements has attribute `title` equals to `something`
- `:checked` : select only selected check-box
- No espace among selectors above means the Logic operator AND

  ==> `":checkbox[title='something']:checked"`

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log($(':checkbox:checked[title=titlehere]').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' title='titlehere'>
<input type='checkbox' title='titlehere'>
<input type='checkbox' title=''>
<input type='checkbox' title='titlehere' checked>
<input type='checkbox' title='titlehere'>
<input type='checkbox' title=''>
<input type='checkbox' title='titlehere' checked>
```

1. Use `[title='yourtitlevalue']` to get the checkbox with that title
2. Use `.length` to get the number
3. Use `:checked` to get only checked checkbox

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type='checkbox' title='my-title' name='checkboxes' class='checkboxes'>
<input type='checkbox' title='my-title2' name='checkboxes' class='checkboxes'>
```

JS

```
$('.checkboxes').change(function () {
  var checked = $(":checkbox[name='checkboxes']:checked");
  checked.each(function(){
    // check similar titles
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type='checkbox' title='my-title' name='checkboxes' class='checkboxes'>
<input type='checkbox' title='my-title2' name='checkboxes' class='checkboxes'>
<input type='checkbox' title='my-title2' name='checkboxes' class='checkboxes'>
<input type='checkbox' title='my-title2' name='checkboxes' class='checkboxes'>
```

jQuery

```
function GetCheckboxesLength(title) {
    var $checkboxes = $('.checkboxes');
    var isChecked;
    var checkboxTitle;
    var length = 0;

    $checkboxes.each(function () {
        isChecked = $(this).is(':checked')
        checkboxTitle = $(this).attr('title');

        if (isChecked && checkboxTitle == title) {
            length++;
        }
    });

    return length;
}

GetCheckboxesLength('my-title2');
```